# Using predicates to update a list in prolog

Tags: list, prolog, predicate, swi-prolog

I am so addicted to functional programming, prepositional programming is foreign to me, I need to implement a  game using prolog. I have defined a list of cards as

```
deck([(ace, spade), (two,spade), (three, spade),(four, spade), (five, spade), (six, spade), (seven, spade),
    (eight, spade), (nine, spade), (ten, spade),(jack, spade),(queen, spade), (king, heart),
    (ace, club), (two,club), (three, club),(four, club), (five, club), (six, club), (seven, club),
    (eight, club), (nine, club), (ten, club),(jack, club),(queen, club), (king, club),
    (ace, heart), (two,heart), (three, heart),(four, heart), (five, heart), (six, heart), (seven, heart),
    (eight, heart), (nine, heart), (ten, heart),(jack, heart),(queen, heart), (king, heart),
    (ace, diamond), (two,diamond), (three, diamond),(four, diamond), (five, diamond), (six, diamond), (seven, diamond),
    (eight, diamond), (nine, diamond), (ten, diamond),(jack, diamond),(queen, diamond), (king, diamond)
    ]
).
```

The first exercise is to create an initial dealer for the deck
The specifications are

```
% Deals the cards from the `Deck`. The initial deal consists of two cards given 
% to the player and two cards for the house. This predicate returns the new deck 
% without just dealt cards and the table i.e. list of lists containing cards of 
% both players.
%
% @param Table    List of cards held by both players (list of lists).
% @param NewDeck  Deck(s) of card with removed cards that were used for initial 
%                 deal.
% @param Deck     Deck(s) of cards used for initial deal.
```

My current trial is this, but I really doubt it works

```
initDeal([], [], []).
initDeal(Table, NewDeck, Deck) :-
    [X, Y, Rest] = Deck,
    FirstNewDeck = Rest,
    [M, N, Final] = NewDeck,
    NewDeck = Final,                                          
    Table = [[X,Y],[M,N]].
```

I will really appreciate any help on this

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Might note that you can't "update a list", you can create a new list.

But you might find it easier to break things up a bit.

Some *facts* defining your suites of cards;

```
suite( clubs    ).
suite( diamonds ).
suite( hearts   ).
suite( spades   ).
```

Some more *facts* defining the pips (face value) of each card, though you'll have to figure out how to deal with the "aces high" vs. "aces low" dichotomy:

```
pips( two   ,  2 ).
pips( three ,  3 ).
pips( four  ,  4 ).
pips( five  ,  5 ).
pips( six   ,  6 ).
pips( seven ,  7 ).
pips( eight ,  8 ).
pips( nine  ,  9 ).
pips( ten   , 10 ).
pips( jack  , 11 ).
pips( queen , 12 ).
pips( king  , 13 ).
pips( ace   , 14 ).
```

Then, assembling a card is easy (on backtracking, it will successively find all 52 possible cards):

```
card( P-S ) :- pips(P,_), suite(S).
```

And assembling a deck is easy, too:

```
deck(Cards) :- findall( C, card(C), Cards ).
```

Once you have that list of cards, shuffling them is almost as easy. The general algorithm:

- Iterate over the list. For each member in the list, assign it a random value as the key using the `-/2` structure: `<key>-<value>`.
- Using the built-in `keysort/2` predicate, sort the list by its key.
- Strip off the key to yield the randomly shuffled list:

```
shuffle( Deck, Shuffled ) :- 
    assign_random_keys(Deck,Ds),
    keysort(Ds,Ss),
    remove_keys(Ss,Shuffled).

assign_random_keys( []     , []       ) .
assign_random_keys( [X|Xs] , [K-X|Ys] ) :- random(K), assign_random_keys(Xs,Ys).

remove_keys( []       , []     ) .
remove_keys( [_-X|Xs] , [X|Ys] ) :- remove_keys(Xs,Ys).
```

Creating a deck and shuffling it is then as easy as:

```
Deck(Cards), shuffle(Deck, Shuffled).
```

See it in action at https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/iFytxOWh.pl

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, it'll help me in revaluating the deck of the cards and you've helped with the implement of the value of a card, but it remains the dealing of the card as per the specifications.... The shuffled function was pre implemented by the tutors ...Thanks a lot